# C/C++ programs in netbeans

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

What are these fields shown in image and how can I fill these?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are the C/C++ compiler and make utility these packages can be downloaded and installed, see this link: https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html

Follow the steps there.

Comment: I had read that document and there is some proxy settings and i am using default proxy settings and working on window 8.1. But still it's not working.And how to fill Base Directory field or how to choose $PATH.